# visual studio auto-formatting

Tags: visual-studio, autoformatting

just a little one.

Visual studio's auto formatting takes the below line of code:

```
<li><a href="<?php print $directorylifts; ?>catered-chalets/index.php">All Catered Chalets</a></li>
```

and turns it into this line of code:

```
    <li>
        <a href=""
            <?php print $directorylifts; ?>catered-chalets/index.php">All Catered Chalets
        </a>
    </li>
```

Note how it's inserted an extra quotation mark after the href= so the code no longer works.

I could just turn off the auto formatting but I find it helpful. Any ideas how to adjust it to stop this happening?

my files have the .php extension.

Thanks,

Phil.

Comment: The original does already have a closing quotation mark.The issue is caused by the < of the php I think - if it's just text then I don't have the issue

Comment: Do you have any PHP tools installed?

Comment: Hi @HansKesting, I don't have any tools installed. I've never used any. Do you think this would fix the issue, and if so would you have any suggestions as to what I should install? Thanks!

Comment: I've never used PHP, so I can't recommend any. Use Tools > Extensions and updates, and search for PHP. My guess is that by installing some PHP tool, you teach VS about the PHP-specific syntax, so it will treat your code correctly.

Comment: thanks for that. I cannot install extensions as I'm using the express version. not to worry, I shall live without it. Thanks anyway!